# An extra long closet and the rod, mounted in concrete, keeps falling off.

Tags: closet

I have an extra long closet and the rod keeps falling off. It is in concrete and the anchors keep coming out. I guess I could put a pole up in the middle to brace it, buy any other ideas???

Comment: Span? Pole construction? Socket type? Anchor type and size? Concrete condition? Help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be bomb proof, (and why wouldn't you?)  you could cut two 2x4s to the height of the rod, drill holes near the top of them, run the rod through those holes, and screw the 2x4s into the wall with a few tapcons or other concrete screw.  The 2x4 will carry the weight to the floor, the screws will just hold them in place on the wall.  You'll be able to go pretty heavy.  (The bottom end of the 2x4s will rest on the ground.)

Answer (score 0):

- Plumbing strap, wire or chain from the ceiling to support it in the middle.
- Closet rod bracket from the wall to support it in the middle.
- Lighter clothing or less clothing hung on it.
- Drill holes through the wall and use a section of iron pipe long
  enough to fit all the way through the walls as a closet rod.
- Move to the moon - lower gravity, less stress on the closet rod.

Comment: The last option sounds interesting...lol. I think I will look for great big screws to hold up the supports

Answer (score 0):

I would cut a 4 x 4 square of 3/4 inch thick plywood to put behind the closet dowel. Buy some concrete self taper screws and a tube of silicone. Level your piece of wood to meet up with your rod and trace the 4x4 onto the concrete wall. Apply silicone to 4x4 piece, stick to wall, and use self taper screws to attach the wood. Once the silicone sets up with the screws it won't go anywhere. Recut your closet dowel and reattach your dowel rod holder to the plywood you attached. You will need a good drill to get the self tapers to take to the concrete.